# WireMock: How to pick out a specific file based on one field in a XML

Tags: xml, mocking, postman, wiremock

I have several XML files. Using wiremock, I wish to select one of the files based on one of its fields.

My mapping JSON file currently looks like this:

```
{
  "priority": 1,
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "url": "/PAXGetEntitlement",

    "bodyPatterns" : [ {
      "equalToXml" : "<RNUM>AE767818</RNUM>"
    } ]
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "text/xml"
    }
  }
}
```

The top (and relevant) part of the file I want to pick out ('AE767818-get-entitlement.xml') looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns:getEntitlementDataResponse xmlns:ns="http://remote.interfaces.dataretrievalservices.pax.curam">
      <ns1:Document xmlns:ns1="http://remote.interfaces.paxdataretrievalservices.pax.curam">
        <GetEntitlementDetailsResponse>
          <ResponseHeader>
            <SessionID>PAX1600425562</SessionID>
            <VersionNumber>1.0</VersionNumber>
            <CompletionIndicator>true</CompletionIndicator>
            <RNUM>AE767818</RNUM>
            <CRN />
            <EventMessages />
          </ResponseHeader>
```

When I send a request from Postman, I get a response saying "Body does not match".

I was under the (seemingly incorrect) impression that I only had to specify 1 field in the equalToXml parameter to get a match but Wiremock is complaining that I'm not specifying the entire body of the file.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Deems a match if the attribute value is valid XML and is semantically equal to the expected XML document.
> [From the XML equality documentation](https://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/#xml-equality). This means that the *entire* body of the request must match the value.

Instead, we can use [xpath matching](https://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/#xpath) to only match if that individual field matches. Something like the following should work:

```js
...
"bodyPatterns" : [ {
      "matchesXPath" : { 
        "expression": "/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ns:getEntitlementDataResponse/ns1:Document/GetEntitlementDetailsResponse/ResponseHeader/RNUM/text()",
        "equalTo": "AE767818"
        }
    } ]
...
```